# Help! How to get contents loaded first before doing anything?

Tags: jquery, load

this is part of my code:

```
// part 1
$('#igPanel .pre').html(contentsLoadHere).addClass('panelShow').removeClass('pre').attr('panelNum',panelNum);

// part 2
$('<div style="  width:0; border:2px solid #FFF; float:left; color:#FFF;" class="slider pre">empty</div>').prependTo('#igPanel').animate({width:200}, function(){

    $('#igPanel .next').remove();
    $('#igPanel .slider:last').html('empty').removeClass('panelShow').addClass('next').removeAttr('panelNum');
});
```

and I want the part 2 executes after the part 1 was finished. Because I want the contents in part 1 "`html(contentsLoadHere)`" loaded first.

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the queue method http://api.jquery.com/queue/

```
// part 1
$('#igPanel .pre').
   queue(function(next){
      $(this).
         html(contentsLoadHere).
         addClass('panelShow').
         removeClass('pre').
         attr('panelNum',panelNum);
         next();
   }).
   queue(function(next){
      $('<div style="  width:0; border:2px solid #FFF; float:left; color:#FFF;" class="slider pre">empty</div>').
          prependTo('#igPanel').animate({width:200}, function(){
              $('#igPanel .next').remove();
              $('#igPanel .slider:last').
                    html('empty').
                    removeClass('panelShow').
                    addClass('next').
                    removeAttr('panelNum');
          });
      next();
   });
```

Comment: Thank you very much.That is the way I want!!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    // ...
    // Your code here
    // ...
});
```

Maybe this helps. It waits for the whole document to be ready to be manipulated and then starts your code. Maybe that it doesn't work right now, because the document is not ready. So just try that :)

Comment: I am so sorry for my poor description. I just want my part 2 code to  execute after part 1 code finishing load contents.

Comment: Isn't that guaranteed, because you wrote part 2 after part 1 in your code? If not you could add an if-statement to check if the code of part 1 is ready.